# String splitting function in Haskell

Tags: strings, haskell

I need to write a function which selects a run of repeated characters from the start of a string, with the run comprising at most nine characters.

```
chomp :: String -> String
chomp str =  takeWhile (== head str) str

munch :: String -> String
munch = take 9 . chomp

runs :: String -> [String]
runs string = extract string [] where
    extract str xs
        | length str == 0 = xs
        | otherwise = extract (drop (length (munch str)) str) (xs ++ [(munch str)])
```

I can't define any new functions (except helper ones), however, I can use all of the haskell built-in ones. Is there a nicer way to write the `runs` function?

**Examples**

```
runs "aaaaabbbbcc"
["aaaaa","bbbb","cc"]

runs "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbcc"
["aaaaaaaaa","aaaaaa","bbbb","cc"]

runs "dddddddddddd"
["ddddddddd","ddd"]

runs "aaabbbaaa"
["aaa","bbb","aaa"]
```

Comment: *"I can only use these 3, user made functions"*. What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @Zeta It means that I can't define any new functions (except helper ones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Another variant of `runs`

Let us start with the finished product first, and then I will show you how to get there:

```
runs :: String -> [String]
runs "" = []
runs xs = munched : runs (drop (length munched) xs)
  where munched = munch xs
```

### Use pattern matching

In your `extract` function, you've checked `str`'s length. However, that is not necessary and is *very* expensive. If you want to check whether a list is empty either use `null` or pattern matching. With pattern matching, we end up with

```
extract []  xs = xs
extract str xs = extract (drop (length (munch str)) str) (xs ++ [(munch str)])
```

### Use bindings to keep repetition low

However, we repeat ourselves here and use `munch str` twice. Let's get rid of that:

```
extract []  xs = xs
extract str xs = extract (drop (length munched) str) (xs ++ [munched])
  where
    munched = munch str
```

Our line got a little bit shorter. Great. Now let us have a look at your accumulator.

### Avoid repeated `++`

Your results looks like this:

```
munch str ++ munch str' ++ munch str'' ++ munch str''' …
```

However, with parentheses, we actually have

```
(…(((munch str ++ munch str') ++ munch str'') ++ munch str''') …)
```

Since `++` is linear in its first argument, that is going to be slow. However, we don't need to use `++` at all, since we're constructing a list element-wise from the first to the last. So instead of an accumulator, let us have `extract` return the list as soon as possible:

```
extract [] = []
extract str = munched : extract (drop (length munched) str)
  where munched = munch str
```

At that point `extract` has exactly the same type as `runs`, so we can get rid of it. We end up with

```
runs :: String -> [String]
runs []  = []
runs str = munched : runs (drop (length munched) str)
  where munched = munch str
```

Replace `str` with `xs` and the first `[]` with `""`, and you have my first variant. We're done.

## Other functions

You could rewrite `chomp` in a way that returns already groups of characters, e.g.

```
chomp "aaaaabbbbbccccc" = ["aaaaa","bbbbb","ccccc"]
```

Then, you could rewrite `munch` so that it splits a string after 9 characters:

```
munch "aaaaaaaaaa" = ["aaaaaaaa","aa"]
```

If you do that, `runs` gets a lot simpler:

```
runs = concatMap munch . chomp
```

However, the types of `chomp` and `munch` would differ in that case. By the way, this variant of `chomp` is in the standard library, and `munch` is also easy to implement.

Comment: Thank you so much.
P.S In runs code snippets it should be munched = munch xs instead of munch str